# Carbonating fruit on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, food, melacha-creative-work, fruits, makeh-befatish

May one perform either of the following actions on Shabbos or Yom Tov?

- Placing fruit into a bin with dry ice, and closing the bin to force the carbon dioxide to sublimate into the fruit
- Connecting a tank of CO2 to a bin containing fruit to carbonate

Would there a problem of הכנה (preparation), מכה בפטיש (the final touch in creating something), or מוליד (creating something new)?

The purpose of the CO2 is to add fizzy taste to the fruit.

Comment: It may depend on why you're doing it (especially since you think the reason it may be forbidden is הכנה or מכה בפטיש). Including that reason in the question, then, may help you get on-point answers. (Personally, I haven't the foggiest notion why someone might want to do either of the two actions described.)

Comment: It is muttar to carbonate water (as in an old-fashioned syphon or a Soda Stream type device), so injecting Co2 in and of itself does not constitute forbidden melacha. But as @msh said, more details are required

Comment: May be a problem of גוזז

Comment: In the second instance, what about boneh?

Comment: The dry ice might be an issue because it could possibly freeze the fruit. There are differences between Sefardi & Ashkenazi minhag in this area. As JoshK mentions above simple carbonation is permissible, particularly if it increases your enjoyment of Shabbat. A good discussion of the subject of freezing things can be seen here: https://israelb.org/2015/08/so-can-you-make-ice-cubes-on-shabbat/

Comment: For further discussion of the issues around freezing things on Shabbat, see here: https://collive.com/making-ice-cubes-on-shabbos/